# Create a scrolling Div within HTML5 phonegap IOS app - without height

Tags: ios, css, html, cordova

Is is possible to create a scrolling div within a html5 IOS app where the height needs to be dynamic?

To give a bit of background to my headache - our app has 3 main panels - the user can left or right swipe to reveal the first and third panel which contain notifications/settings (as in the Facebook app. All 3 outer panels are fixed position.

The main panel contains 6 pages - which are all absolutely positioned divs which hide and show via menu selection.  Each revealed div (or page) needs to scroll, but all content is dynamic - so I cant set a height.

I have found several solutions for fixed heights - but none so far for dynamic heights..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [this Link](http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/)

[iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) is a party lib which help in good scrolling.

It has a scrolling without providing height.
We just have to call a method refresh when dom elements of scrolling are added.

Answer (score 10):

**Scrolling Divs**

Another new feature in iOS 5+ is divs can finally scroll. To make a div scroll you’ll just need to add the following (this example has a fixed header but adjust the positioning to fit your app):

```
.scrollable {
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
overflow: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

The trick here is adding the -webkit-overflow-scrolling to anywhere you’d normally set your overflow. The downside of Apple’s implementation is that the div doesn’t bounce as you’d hope when you are already at the absolute top or bottom. Instead of bouncing the div being scrolled, it bounces the whole page and reveals the browser chrome. This is where you’ll need a javascript fix.

Please try this [example](http://joehewitt.github.com/scrollability/) for Scrollability.

Comment: This is so much better than the other answer, which doesn't even work inside of a jquery mobile dialog.

Comment: Okay, so if I have two divs next to each other that have scrolling content, how can I make it so that if a user does the "scroll to top" action (tap the status bar) only the div under the side they tap scrolls to the top?